# How to get Spring profile name from annotation?

Tags: java, spring

With Spring 3.1 and profiles, creating a custom interface to define specific profiles becomes interesting.  Part of the beauty is the ability to completely forgot the String name of the profile and just use the annotation.

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Profile("Dev")
public @interface Dev {

}
```

And then simply annotate beans with `@Dev`.  This works great.

However, how can I check if the `@Dev` profile is active?  `Environment.acceptsProfiles()` requires a String argument.  Is there a "neat" way of doing this, or is my only option to do something like:

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Profile(Dev.NAME)
public @interface Dev {
    public static String NAME = "Dev";
}


public class MyClass{

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    private void myMethod(){
       if( env.acceptsProfiles( Dev.NAME ) )
          // do something here
        ;
    }
```

Although functional, I'm not particularly fond of this concept.  Is there another way I can do this neater?

Comment: Why are you trying to explicitly check?

Comment: @chrylis Because I need to enable certain things in my front end based on profile selection, so want to pass a boolean flag to the front end jsps

Comment: Hmm. Since you're trying to abstract away the profile name in the first place, I think you'll either have to trace the meta-annotation path or perhaps register a bean conditional on the profile.

Comment: @chrylis I don't quite understand your suggestions.  Do you mean use reflection for tracing the meta-annotation path (yeech)?  And what do you mean by a bean conditional on the profile?

Comment: Yup, reflection is how Spring handles the meta-annotation path. And I mean something like registering a bean that returns "true" if `@Dev` and that returns "false" if not `@Dev` (though admittedly, this might get into Spring Boot territory with `@ConditionalOnBean`, at which point I'd just jump to configuration properties anyway).

Comment: @Chrylis That's kind of what I figured you meant about registering a bean.  but that's such a clunky solution.  I was hoping there would be something more elegant.

Answer (score 5):

I wanted to do something similar (in my case, represent a list of synonyms under one profile annotation) but I ran into the problem your having, as well as another limitation: You won't be able to apply more than one of the annotations to a single bean and have them both get picked up by `spring` (at least in `spring 3`).

Unfortunately, as you cannot pass the enum in, the solution I settled on was to just use plain-old string constants without the enum. Then I could do something like `@Profile(CONSTANT_ONE, CONSTANT_TWO)`. I still benefited from not being able to make typos, but also gained the ability to still apply multiple profiles to the same bean.

Not perfect, but not too bad.

Comment: Thanks - I was looking for something a little more elegant and figured there had to be something else available.